# difference between when I use 'each' in the middle or at the end to refer to the subject of a clause

Tags: word-usage, adverb-placement

This article says 'each' usually appears in the normal middle position for adverbs when it is used to refer to the subject of a clause. [dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/each](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/each)

Here is an exmaple:

> We would each say a poem or sing a song.

A grammar book gives another sentence where 'each' appears at the end:

> These oranges cost 25 pence each.

In this usage, is there meaning difference between both possible positions where 'each' could appear?  For example, between 'These oranges cost 25 pence each.' and 'These oranges each cost 25 pence.'

Comment: Please read this article about adverb placement. If you still have questions after reading it, please edit your question to add details. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks, the content of the article is really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. There are two things going on here:

## Floating quantifiers

A few words expressing quantities—"both", "all", "each"—are flexible in that they can appear in different places without changing the meaning.

To elaborate on your example, the following are equivalent:

- **Each of us** would say a poem or sing a song.
- We **each** would say a poem or sing a song.
- We would **each** say a poem or sing a song.

"All" and "both" are syntactically valid in all these locations as well.

## Rate expressions

Another use of "each" is expressing a rate where the set of items quantified over is established in context. "Apiece" can also be used here. The following are equivalent:

- These oranges cost 25 pence **each**/**apiece**.
- The cost was 25 pence **per orange**.

Just like you could say *We sang one song per person*, you could say *We sang a song each*. But it would have to be *We each graduated* or *Each of us graduated*, not **We graduated each*.

Comment: +1. When an auxiliary verb is present, the mid position is generally between auxiliary verb and the main verb "We would each say*. As this NGram graph shows, placing the adverb before the auxiliary verb "we would each say" does occur, though much less frequently.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+would+each%2C+we+each+would&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20would%20each%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20each%20would%3B%2Cc0